# Wordpress: Show subcategories after the category is selected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Here's the scenario: I'm using Wordpress categories as states and child-categories as cities. On the front-end part, i'm showing a `<select>` through `wp_dropdown_categories` with the states only.

Is it possible to, when i change the state, it creates another `<select>` tag below with the subcategories to it's relative parent?

Comment: need it with array arguments

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can do it by make an ajax request when state selected, get all child categories of state and fill it in city select box.